# How can I get the service from a `HttpServletRequest` in Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, service, tomcat8

How can I get the service from a `HttpServletRequest` in Tomcat 8?

In tomcat 7 mapper is in the `Connector` so I was able to access the Mapper as

```
((Request) request).getConnector().getMapper() //request is a HttpServletRequest
```

But how can I obtain this in Tomcat 8?
In the tomcat 8 migration documentation it is said that

> The Mapper has moved from the Connector to the Service since the
>   Mapper is identical for all Connectors of a given Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tomcat developers just moved the mapper to [Service](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Service.html#getMapper()). So use:

```
((Request) request).getConnector().getService().getMapper()
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I figured that out

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getFullURL(HttpServletRequest request) {
StringBuffer requestURL = request.getRequestURL();
String queryString = request.getQueryString();

if (queryString == null) {
    return requestURL.toString();
} else {
    return requestURL.append('?').append(queryString).toString();
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I want to access the StandardService in-order to get the Mapper.

Comment: standred service means?

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardService.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured the way
I have to get the service from the Connector

```
getConnector().getService().getMapper()
```